# how to show if no result given date range and 0 result with django annotate?

Tags: django, postgresql, highcharts, django-views

With results showing correctly but if no results how to show date and 0 result

```
pre_days = datetime.datetime.today() - timedelta(days=6)
today_now = datetime.datetime.today()
enquiry_chart = All_enquiries.objects.filter(enquired_at__range=[pre_days, today_now]).values('enquired_at__date').annotate(enquired=Count('id'))
```

example
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *don't*. A database uses the *minimal world* assumption. This means that if no data is present, then it does not exists.

You can however add extra values yourself. For example with:

```
num_days = 6
today_now = datetime.datetime.today()
pre_days = today_now - timedelta(days=num_days)
temp = All_enquiries.objects.filter(
    enquired_at__range=[pre_days, today_now]
).values('enquired_at__date').annotate(
    enquired=Count('id')
)
tempdict = {
    row['enquired_at__date']: row['enquired']
    for row in temp
}

result = [
    {
        'enquired_at__date': (pre_days+timedelta(days=k)).date(),
        'enquired': tempdict.get((pre_days+timedelta(days=k)).date(), 0)
    }
    for k in range(num_days+1)
]
```

We thus first contruct a dictionary where we map the date on the number of records, and then we construct a list of records again, where we will use zero for missing values.

Comment: {'enquired_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 18, 45, 34, 438776), 'enquired': 0}, {'enquired_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 2, 18, 45, 34, 438776), 'enquired': 0}, {'enquired_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 3, 18, 45, 34, 438776), 'enquired': 0}, {'enquired_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 4, 18, 45, 34, 438776), 'enquired': 0}, {'enquired_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 5, 18, 45, 34, 438776), 'enquired': 0}, {'enquired_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 6, 18, 45, 34, 438776), 'enquired': 0}, {'enquired_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 7, 18, 45, 34, 438776), 'enquired': 0}]

Comment: date showing correctly but values showing 0 but in database i have 10 10 records

Comment: @ManjuanthVM: yes I made a mistake. I think now it should be fixed.